# How can I use serial port in C# Silverlight 4.0 application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, serial-port

How can I use serial port in a Silverlight 4.0 application?

Comment: If you need access to the serial port you should seriously reconsider choice of Silverlight as your platform.

Comment: possible duplicate of [use com control in silverlight application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555963/use-com-control-in-silverlight-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Silverlight 4, this is only possible via COM, and only out of browser.

Here is [an article showing how it can be done](http://tech-michael.blogspot.com/2009/12/silverlight-talking-to-arduino.html).

Usage while in-browser or directly is prohibited by Silverlight's runtime.

Comment: I searched this link and tried to code as it is, but i m not able to get ComAutomationFactory, pls help me more

Comment: I think that all the stuff is for OOB application, but how can i do it with silverlight web-hosted browser application.?

Comment: @Akhil: You can't - this is unsupported within the browser sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use P/Invoke with Silverlight 5 to talk to Win32 libraries directly.  Basically your re-writing the .NET SerialPort class.  That's exactly what Ive done.